# Google Calendar list not visible for Service Accounts using api

Tags: https, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I am new to Google Calendar API, I had created the Service Account for OAuth process and then I get the access token using JWT. Then I try to fetch the calendar list but the response didn't fetch the calendar list. I am using business account with domain. I want to view my organization user calendar list.

Response:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#calendarList",
  "etag": "\"p3208dll2qn2d60g\"",

  "nextSyncToken": "CICG1qLVxNMCEjBtZWV0aW5nQHBvbGV0dXMtY2FsZW5kYXIuaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20=",
  "items": []
}
```

The Organization user having the SuperAdmin access.
And I tested with my normal gmail account using service accounts it works for all api requests.

Answer (score 1):

Remember a service account is not you.  A service account is a dummy user it has its own Google calendar account.   Assuming that you did share the calendar in question with the Service account it may not have been added to the calendar list.

All calendar list is the list on the bottom left hand side of the GUI.  Sometimes when you share a calendar with a service account it doesn't get added properly to the calendar list.  You can add it yourself via the service account by running [calendarlist.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert)

Assuming that you have not granted the server account permissions to read the calendar you will need to do so by sharing it like you would any other user using the service account email address.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DalmTo. I understood your points. Likewise i need all user details in one organization using service account oauth  but when i tried with 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users' this url and get the access token using this above url but when i run the url using access token it throws '404 - Bad Request' error. I have added the service account client id with scope url 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user' in admin console(Advanced settings--Manage API Client Access) and authorize it but it throws a error for my api user detail request.

Comment: That endpoint isn't going to get a access token and you need an access token to use it.

Comment: Is it possible to have you in a call so we can talk?

Comment: I think you should do some research on service accounts I dont know what language you are working with the client library for your language should support service accounts.   try reading https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccountand http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/