# Get All Calendars in Google Org via Google API

Tags: google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

**Goal**: I'm trying to get all the calendars in my Gsuite org.

**Problem**: I know I can get a list of calendars using `CalendarList.list` but that's only if the user or service account has all the calendars in its list and even then it's not always accurate because the calendars don't always get added to the [service account's calendar list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43659119/12358059) and a user could potentially remove the calendar from their list.

**Question**: Is there a way to just grab every calendar in my Google org? Let's say my domain is @someorg.com. I want every user's calendar as well as calendars created through the api. I was thinking this might be possible with the GSuite Admin SDK, but I haven't been able to find anything that allows me to do this. It only handles `Resources.calendars` which is different than a `Calendar` object.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This might be better in the webapps forum. Take a look over there for posts that are similar.
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/cant-find-a-calendar-as-admin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck :\ Also, I'm looking for a solution using the Google API, not the app.

Comment: @Rodger this is a programming question not a GSuite web application question.  Web apps wont be able to help getting the information back with a service account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.   The only way to get a list of calendars that the user has access to is though the `calendarlist.list` method. The issue with this is that you must be sure that all of the users' calendars were actually added to `calendarlist` which is not always the case.

What you can do is prompt the user asking them to share with you any other calendars but that's not going to work very well with a service account.

Comment: Marking this correct. Ended up just doing this manually. Like DalmTo mentions above, it's not possible to get all calendars including service account created calendars.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the service account to get a token for each user, for this you need each user's email which you can get making a Users.list request [1]. With each token you can do a CalendarList.list request [2] for each impersonated user which will retrieve you the user's calendars it's subscribed to.

You can filter the results to get the calendars with the `accessRole` [3] field set to `owner`, if you want the calendars created by the user. You could get the deleted calendars as well by setting the `showDeleted` parameter to true [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list

[2] https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list

[3] https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList

Comment: This is actually a pretty good idea :) Do you know if [1] will also return service account user emails? Besides the actual user calendars, I also have calendars created by a service account that belong to the service account as well. Thanks!

Comment: No sorry I don't know, you could test it and see. If not, you could do a workaround giving access to the the service account calendars to a single user and retrieve those calendars through that user, and may be filter by one of the calendar fields

Comment: If it helped you, please consider accepting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @AndresDuarte I see you have 3 footnotes but none of the footnote references mention #3. Should one point to it in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the official documentation provided by Workspace(formerly G-Suite), this can be achieved by using service accounts with `domain-wide authority delegation`.

Please check the documentations below:

- [Google Calendar API - Domain Resources](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/domain)
- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)