# Add my personal calendar to Service account

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Add my personal calendar to Service account

Hello Folks.
I'm trying to share my personal calendar with Service Account.

I've read several posts saying that I have to add my service account email in the "Share with specific people or groups" field, I've already done that.

[image]

I also read in several posts (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658666/google-calendar-list-not-visible-for-service-accounts-using-api)) that this alone is not enough, I also have to insert it into calendar.list manually.

I've already looked at the tutorial on this [page](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) but I couldn't understand how to insert my personal calendar to the service account.

This is a snippets of my code. But as I wrote the problem is not with my code, as I am using ServiceAccountCredential to login my personnal calendar do not appears as part of ServiceAccountCredential.

```
Dim Request As EventsResource.ListRequest = service2.Events.List("primary")
    Request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now
    Request.ShowDeleted = False
    Request.SingleEvents = True
    Request.MaxResults = 10
    Request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime
    MsgBox("Upcoming events:")
    Dim events As Events = request.Execute()

    If events.Items.Count > 0 Then
        For Each eventItem In events.Items
            Dim [when] As String = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString()

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty([when]) Then
                [when] = eventItem.Start.Date
            End If
            MsgBox("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, [when])
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox("No upcoming events found.")
    End If
```

Could someone help me by giving me an example of how to do this inclusion.

Now I found out one code to add my personal calendar to the service account calendar list (this code below)

[image]

But it thrown an "Not found" exception, and I used my email which is the ID of my calendar...

I also tried to execute it with the word "primary" as my calendar ID, but this time it thrown an error saying "Cannot change your own access level"..

[image]

Can someone take a look and say what I'm doing wrong.. Please
Thank you.

Comment: I have tested this on my end and it seems that I was able to make this work properly using the calendarList.insert . I have used python in this replication process. If you can provide a copy of your code, or project snippets the community will have better chance to help you and figure out what type of help you need.

Comment: Hello Babanana.. Thank you for your replay.. I added my code to my question, but I'd like to highlight that the code is working fine, my problem is how to add my personal calendar to the ServiceAccount.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Eduardo. The steps I took, is that I shared my personal calendar to the service account manuallly, then I enabled the Calendar API on my  Google Cloud Console, and then use this https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/insert to add it and when i run my list calendar on service account the personal account  shows up.

Comment: Hi.. Babanana.. surely I'm doing something wrong, because I tried to run this command (https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy@gmail.com/calendarList) and it gives me an error... (was not found on this server) could you help me identify what's missing...?

Comment: I am no expert with VB Language, and I cannot see the whole end point you are request data from. But there is a strong chance that you might calling a wrong end point, because the email should be on the request body and not on the endpoint.

Comment: hi Babanana.. Thank you for the replay. Can you give an exmple of how do you did, no mather the language you used..?